# i already set the body, html element height 100% even then div element height 100% is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

If i set the div element height in pixels then my div element taking height property and its working perfectly. But i want it other way . I know that if i want to set my div element height in as percentage value than i first need to set my body and html element height in percentage value. And i did but it's not working.

```css
body, html {
  height:100%;
  
}

.navigation-area{
   background-color:#DDD;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
  
}

.navigation-area a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  float:left
  
}

.slider-area {
  margin-top:50px;
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/parallax1.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class= "main">
 <div class="navigation-area">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>About</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-th"></i>Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>Contacts</a>
  <a href="#" class="right"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="slider-area">
  <div class="text-area">
   <span>MY <span>WEBSITE</span>LOGO</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="content-area">
  <p>The example above used pixels to set the height of the image. If you want to use percent, for example 100%, to make the image fit the whole screen, set the height of the parallax container to 100%. Note: You must also </p>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: missing height:100% on `.main`

Answer (score 0):

Use view height 100% for it

```
.slider-area {
```

height: 100vh;

}

Comment: thank you , but i saw same code working in w3school websites. why mine's not working?

Comment: please try this. previous one was my mistake. i apologize for it :)

Comment: okay, but can you tell me why is this one working<br>
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_parallax_percent

Comment: yes you can see they did a inline css there <div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px"> that's why its working there.

Comment: yes i can see but i think you didn't got the problem, i have nothing to with my content-area div element. My problem and the question is why my slider-area div is not taking 100% height value

Comment: oh i see.. You can set the hight value depending on the user device view hight by adding height: 100vh....

Comment: but why it's not working in my code. it's working perfectly in w3school website

Comment: i believe i have found the problem. it says "to make the image fit the whole screen, set the height of the parent container to 100%." my slider-area div element immediate parent container is main div element. that's why i need to set height property of that element first :) thank you @Raw Scripter for giving a try

Comment: awesome. welcome dude :)

Answer (score 0):

to set the height 100% of a element you need to set height 100% of that element immediate parent element with body and html element height 100%